# Build external url in Rails that look nice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am rendering an external link with this view:

```
  <%= link_to public_web(company), class:" text-sm text-decoration-none", :target => "_blank" do %>
    <i class="fa fa-globe mr-3"></i>
    <span class="text-muted"><%=  "#{public_web(company)}" %></span>
  <% end %>
```

and the following helper

```
  def public_web(company)
    URI::HTTPS.build({:host => company.marketings.first.try(:website)}).to_s 
  end
```

However the url length breaks the UI design (I would like to control the maximum length)

How can I truncate it ?

Solution :

I modified the helper as follows:

```
  def public_web(company)
    response = URI::HTTPS.build({:host => company.marketings.first.try(:website)}).to_s
    truncate(response, length: 25, omission: '...')
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking to truncate the text of the link then this is one way

```
<%= link_to public_web(company).truncate(20), class:" text-sm text-decoration-none", :target => "_blank" do %>
  <i class="fa fa-globe mr-3"></i>
  <span class="text-muted"><%= public_web(company) %></span>
<% end %>
```

Read more on the [`truncate`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-truncate) method in Rails